# How to print the anchor tags and its values of the web element in reverse order in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to retrieve the anchor tags and anchor tag values from a html page, i'm using selenium in java to retrieve the html code of the page. But i need to print the anchor tags and anchor tag values in the **reverse order, but not sorting.**

My html code look like this :-

```
<div id="container">
<a href="www.flipkart.com">"Flipkart"</a>
<a href="www.amazon.com">"Amazon"</a>
<a href="www.ebay.com">"Ebay"</a>
<a href="www.newegg.com">"NewEgg"</a>
</div>
```

My Java code that i'm using to retrieve those anchor tag's is look like this:-

```
 List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='container']//a[@href]"));
            for (WebElement element : list) {
                String link = element.getAttribute("href");
                System.out.println("Link: " + link + ", Title: " + element.getText());
```

The Output I'm getting like this:-

```
Link: www.flipkart.com , Title: Flipkart
Link: www.amazon.com , Title: Amazon
Link: www.ebay.com , Title: Ebay
Link: www.newegg.com , Title: NewEgg
```

But, The output i required is as follows:-

```
Link: www.newegg.com , Title: NewEgg
Link: www.ebay.com , Title: Ebay
Link: www.amazon.com , Title: Amazon
Link: www.flipkart.com , Title: Flipkart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following to reverse the list:

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

So the final code would look like this:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='container']//a[@href]"));
Collections.reverse(list);
for (WebElement element : list) {
    String link = element.getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println("Link: " + link + ", Title: " + element.getText());
}
```

Comment: @infoinside You're welcome! Please make sure to mark the answer as accepted now that it worked fine for you.